# ¿Cuál es la sintaxis de un Trigger?

Tags: sql, trigger

Creo que está mal y no lo puedo comprobar, a ver si alguien sabe.

Es un trigger que se dispara después de que se actualice la Localidad (loc) de la tabla departamento (depart), una vez actualizada se coge a los empleados de la tabla emple que pertenecen a ese departamento que ha cambiado de localidad y se les sube un 20% el sueldo.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER traslado
AFTER UPDATE OF Loc
ON DEPART FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
vdep number;
BEGIN
SELECT dept_no INTO vdep FROM depart;
UPDATE emple
SET SALARIO=salario+salario*20/100
WHERE vdep=dept_no;
END;
```

Comment: ¿Qué manejador de base de datos utilizas?

Comment: ¿Como eso que no lo puedes comprobar?

Answer (score 1):

aqui te dejo la sintaxis para crear un trigger en sql

```
CREATE TRIGGER <Nombre del Trigger>
ON <Nombre de la Tabla>
AFTER <INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE>
  AS
BEGIN
-- Inserta aquí las instrucciones
END
```

la parte de **OF Loc** puedes lograrla mediante una condicion dentro del trigger algo como esto

```
if NEW.loc <> OLD.loc THEN
```

Comment: Depende del motor de base de datos, y por ahora, no está claro cual es.